# How to get only filename without extension?

Tags: python, pandas, stem

Imagine you have these paths of files you want to get the filename without extension from:

```
                       relfilepath
0                  20210322636.pdf
12              factuur-f23622.pdf
14                ingram micro.pdf
19    upfront.nl domein - Copy.pdf
21           upfront.nl domein.pdf
Name: relfilepath, dtype: object
```

I came up with the following however this gives me the problem that for the first item it becomes a number outputting '20210322636.0'.

```
from pathlib import Path


for i, row in dffinalselection.iterrows():
    dffinalselection['xmlfilename'][i] = Path(dffinalselection['relfilepath'][i]).stem
    dffinalselection['xmlfilename'] = dffinalselection['xmlfilename'].astype(str)
```

This is wrong since it should be '20210322636'

Please help!

Comment: assuming the file extension is the last three characters . . . `df['relfilepath'].str[:-4]`

Comment: Thanks you but sometimes, there are jpegs involved.. So that would not work

Comment: Use the `.name` method on `Path` objects. Note, not sure how reasonable it is to put `Path` objects in a `pd.DataFrame`, although, if it is already using `object` dtype I guess it can't hurt. As an aside, you really shouldn't be iterating over a dataframe like this. Use `df.at[ ] = whatever` indexing...

Comment: thank you but I want the file w/o extensions

Comment: Whoops, I meant `Path.stem`, which you are already using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the column values are always the filename/filepath, split it from right on `.` with maxsplit parameter as `1` and take the first value after splitting.

```py
>>> df['relfilepath'].str.rsplit('.', n=1).str[0]

0                  20210322636
12              factuur-f23622
14                ingram micro
19    upfront.nl domein - Copy
21           upfront.nl domein
Name: relfilepath, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You were doing it correctly, but your operaiton on the dataframe was incorrect.

```
from pathlib import Path


for i, row in dffinalselection.iterrows():
    dffinalselection['xmlfilename'][i] = Path(dffinalselection['relfilepath'][i]).stem # THIS WILL NOT RELIABLY MUTATE THE DATAFRAME
    dffinalselection['xmlfilename'] = dffinalselection['xmlfilename'].astype(str) # THIS OVERWROTE EVERYTHING
```

Instead, just do:

```
from pathlib import Path

dffinalselection['xmlfilename'] = ''
for row in dffinalselection.itertuples():
    dffinalselection.at[row.index, 'xmlfilename']= Path(row.relfilepath).stem
```

Or,

```
dffinalselection['xmlfilename'] = dffinalselection['relfilepath'].apply(lambda value: Path(value).stem)
```